# add minutes to unixtimestamp shell script

Tags: unix-timestamp

I want to add minutes to the unix timestamp. For example -

```
date1=$(date +%s)
```

I want to add minutes to the unixtimestamp using shell script. Something like -

`datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=60)` in python

Comment: Try `date1=$(date +%s -d 'now + 7 min')` will add 7 minutes to the current time and display result in seconds.

Comment: Throws an error: date: illegal time format

Comment: In that case you have to specify what unix platform you are running.

Comment: I am using centos

Comment: It's odd. I am using CentOS as well. You are probably using a non-CentOS released `date` binary. Can you try running `/bin/date --date=7m +%s`?

Comment: I meant to type `date --date='now + 7 min' +%s`.

Comment: How can I specify a variable instead of a specific number. For ex - `p=10`;`date --date='now + $p min' +%s`

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes. Try `date --date="now + $p min" +%s`.